# What's wrong with ADT constructor for SquareMatrix?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, overloading

This project I am writing in order to create a Square Matrix ADT object has a problem with the constructor (not the default constructor). I have traced the problem back to the constructor but I cannot figure out what is wrong with it which makes it crash everytime I try to run my test in main.cpp.

I usually get an error that say something along the lines "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS: ..." and the console usually says "(11db)"

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be causing all the problems?

This is the header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#ifndef SquareMatrix_h
#define SquareMatrix_h

class SquareMatrix {
private:
    vector<vector<double>> numMatrix;
public:
     SquareMatrix();
     SquareMatrix(vector<vector<double>>& v2d);
     double getValue(int x, int y);
     void setValue(int x, int y, double value);
     friend SquareMatrix operator * (SquareMatrix m1, SquareMatrix m2);
     friend SquareMatrix operator - (SquareMatrix m1, SquareMatrix m2);
     friend ostream& operator <<(ostream &out, SquareMatrix m);
};

#endif /* SquareMatrix_h */
```

This is my SquareMatrix.cpp file: **(The constructor that I believe isn't working is the second function in the code: *SquareMatrix::SquareMatrix(vector>& v2d) {*...)**

```
#include "SquareMatrix.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

SquareMatrix::SquareMatrix() {
    numMatrix.clear();
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        vector<double> initial;
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            initial.push_back(0.0);
        }
        numMatrix.push_back(initial);
    }
}

SquareMatrix::SquareMatrix(vector<vector<double>>& v2d) {
    bool flagSize = true;

    for(int i = 0; i < v2d.size(); i++) {
        if(v2d[i].size() != v2d.size()) {
            flagSize = false;
            break;
        }
    }

   if(flagSize) {
        numMatrix.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < v2d.size(); i++) {
            vector<double> initial;
            for(int j = 0; j < v2d[i].size(); i++) {
                initial.push_back(v2d[i][j]);
            }
            numMatrix.push_back(initial);
        }
    } else {
        numMatrix.clear();
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            vector<double> initial;
            for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                initial.push_back(0.0);
            }
             numMatrix.push_back(initial);
        }
    }
}

double SquareMatrix::getValue(int x, int y) {
    if((x < numMatrix.size()) && (y < numMatrix.size()) && (x >= 0) && (y >= 0)) {
        return numMatrix[x][y];
    }
    return 0;
 }

void SquareMatrix::setValue(int x, int y, double value) {
    if((x < numMatrix.size()) && (y < numMatrix.size()) && (x >= 0) && (y >= 0)) {
        numMatrix[x][y] = value;
    }
}

SquareMatrix operator * (SquareMatrix m1, SquareMatrix m2) {
    if(m1.numMatrix.size() == m2.numMatrix.size()) {

        vector<vector<double>> result;
        for(int i = 0; i < m1.numMatrix.size(); i++) {
            vector<double> initial;
            for(int j = 0; j < m1.numMatrix.size(); j++) {
                initial.push_back(0);
            }
            result.push_back(initial);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < m1.numMatrix.size(); i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < m1.numMatrix.size(); j++) {
                result[i][j] = 0;
                for (int a = 0; a < m1.numMatrix.size(); a++) {
                    result[i][j] += m1.numMatrix[i][a] + m2.numMatrix[a][j];
                }

            }
        }

        return SquareMatrix(result);
    }

    return SquareMatrix();
}

SquareMatrix operator - (SquareMatrix m1, SquareMatrix m2) {
    if(m1.numMatrix.size() == m2.numMatrix.size()) {
           vector<vector<double>> result;
           for(int i = 0; i < m1.numMatrix.size(); i++) {
                vector<double> initial;
                for(int j = 0; j < m1.numMatrix[i].size(); j++) {
                     double pushNum = (m1.getValue(i,j) - m2.getValue(i,j));
                     initial.push_back(pushNum);
              } 
              result.push_back(initial);
          }
          return SquareMatrix(result);
      }
      return SquareMatrix();
  }

 ostream& operator << (ostream &out, SquareMatrix m) {
    out << "(";
    for (int i = 0; i < m.numMatrix.size(); i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < m.numMatrix.size(); j++) {
             out << " " << m.numMatrix[i][j];
             if(j != (m.numMatrix.size() - 1)) {
                 out << ", ";
             }
        }
    }
     out << ")";

    return out;
}
```

Then this is the main.cpp that I am using to test the SquareMatrix ADT object:

```
#include "SquareMatrix.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    srand(time(NULL));

    vector<vector<double>> m1;
    vector<vector<double>> m2;
    int size = 0;

    cout << "Enter the size of the Square Matrix: ";
    cin >> size;

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        vector<double> in1;
        vector<double> in2;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            in1.push_back(rand() % 100);
            in2.push_back(rand() % 100);
        }
        m1.push_back(in1);
        m2.push_back(in2);
    }

    SquareMatrix res1 = SquareMatrix(m1);
    SquareMatrix res2 = SquareMatrix(m2);

    cout<< "\nMatrix 1: " << endl;
    cout << res1 << endl;

    cout<< "\nMatrix 2: " << endl;
    cout << res2 << endl;

    SquareMatrix mult = res1*res2;
    cout << "\nMatrix1 * Matrix 2: " << endl;
    cout << mult << endl;

    SquareMatrix min1_2 = res1 - res2;
    cout << "Matrix1 - Matrix 2: " << endl;
    cout << min1_2 << endl;

    SquareMatrix min2_1 = res2 - res1;
    cout << "Matrix2 - Matrix 1: " << endl;
    cout << min2_1 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Any help you could give would be appreciated. :)

Comment: You have a typo. Change `for(int j = 0; j < v2d[i].size(); i++)` to `for(int j = 0; j < v2d[i].size(); j++)`. The increment needs to be `j++`.

Comment: oh... wow. now it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, you problem is a simple typo in one of your nested loops. However, I'd like to add some recommendations to make your code less error prone (and also more readable).

Firstly, when iterating over all elements of a vector, unless you need an index for something else, you should be using [a range-based for-loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for). In your code, you might replace the check for square size with the following:

```
for (const vector<double>& vec: v2d){
    if (vec.size() != v2d.size()){
        flagSize = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

This expresses your intent a little more clearly, and, more importantly, prevents you from accidentally reading from/writing to a location out of your vector's bounds (accidentally typing <= instead of just < happens to the best of us).

Secondly, the two nested loops (that contained your error) can be replaced with a simple copy assignment (`numMatrix = v2d`; [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D)). Again, this expresses your intent in addition to being a whole lot shorter. No need to reinvent the wheel with functions like these.

The contents of the else-branch of the surrounding if-statement can also be replaced with a call to [assign](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) (the first overload listed on the page, use like `numMatrix.assign(10, vector<double>(10, 0.0))`). Like before, clearer expression of intent and avoidance of index errors.

Finally, the parameter in this constructor can be a const reference instead of a normal one since you do not alter its contents in any way (and, given this, it should be const).

You might wonder why "expression of intent" is relevant, or what it even means in this context. Essentially, it's all about making what you're trying to do immediately obvious to any reader. This is more important in large projects with many contributors but it is helpful even when debugging small applications like this one. You seem to be learning still, but I strongly believe it's a good thing to keep in mind from the beginning. After all, many of these changes also make for briefer code, making it that much easier for others to help you if you run into a problem.

I realize this left the scope of the original question somewhat, but I hope you find this helpful nonetheless.